# Open multiple files in split mode from within Vim (not command-line)

Tags: split, multiple-files

From within an existing Vim session, I am looking for a technique to achieve the equivalent of `-o file1 file2 file3`.  The `:sp[lit]` command just seems to create a single new split--it doesn't allow for opening multiple splits simultaneously.  It seems like this should be possible, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these:

```
args file1 file2 file3|vert all
```

or

```
args file1 file2 file3|all
```

`all` rearranges the screen to open one window for each argument. See help for more information.

Note the `|` is not used like a pipe, in Vim it's the command separator.